# C pointer assignment isnt working using gcc

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int* p;
    (*p) = 5;
    printf("%i\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile and run this I get the error "test.exe not working", is this because of the compiler?

Comment: p is uninitialized.

Comment: And this should do what?  Besides overwriting OS protected memory and such...

Comment: Yes, it is the compiler.  It ate something that disagreed with it.

Comment: My compiler reports: *warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'p' used*. It is a good idea to get a clean compilation before running the program.

Comment: I suggest that you learn about pointers *before* trying to use them.  It looks like you're just trying to guess at how they work, which is probably doomed to failure.

Comment: @TomKarzes: I suggest you learn about people *before* trying to help them. It looks like you’re just trying to guess at how they work, which is probably doomed to failure. (Really, is it too much trouble to phrase things in an encouraging and guiding manner instead of an off-putting manner? Obviously OP is trying to learn about pointers before using them in any serious program. They are learning by experimenting. That is a perfectly fine method, probably being used in conjunction with other learning techniques. So your “advice” is misguided.)

Comment: I don’t see much wrong with this question: it has a compilable example, and the output is supplied. Yes the conjecture that the compiler is at fault can irritate but that still doesn’t imply a poor question.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why do you write `(*p) = 5;`? The () is not needed here and doesn't make it more readable. Just write `*p = 5;`.

Comment: @Bathsheba not a poor question? what would you call it then, too trivial?!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have no problem with people experimenting with something before researching it (misguided though the approach may be).  I do have a problem with their posting pointless questions to SO when they could simply take a few minutes to find an existing answer.  That is contrary to the purpose of SO.  I suggest you learn the conventions of SO *before* criticizing some else's perfectly legitimate criticism of a question.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The OP believed something was wrong in their understanding of assignments via pointers. The actual error was a mistake in their understanding of definitions of pointers. Show us a search phrase involving “pointer assignment” that would find the needed answer on Stack Overflow or the web. Even if you find one, attempting the task should reveal to you how difficult it is to find information that corrects a mistaken belief you did not know you have.

Comment: @TomKarzes: As an example, I checked the index of K&R, second edition. There is no entry for “pointer assignment,” but I did check “pointer, declaration of.” On the first page listed, it says “The declaration of the pointer `ip`, `int *ip;` is intended as a mnemonic; it says that the expression `*ip` is an `int`.” So a reader may well get the impression that, once they have declared `int *ip;`, they should be able to use `*ip` as an `int`, and `*ip = 5;` ought to assign 5 to an `int`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's a much more reasonable point.  For what it's worth, I typed `C pointer assignment` into Google (no quotes), and at the top of the result list was a "featured" result: [Pointers](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html)  Seems to cover the basics, and it did emphasize that pointers need to be initialized before they can be used.

Answer (score 4):

You are writing to uninitialized memory.  The operating system is killing your application to protect itself from your clumsy memory overwrite attack.  Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int r;               // Let's give p something valid to look at
    int* p = &r;         // Assign the address of r into the p pointer.
    (*p) = 5;            // Write to what is pointed to by p (into r)
    printf("%i\n", *p);  // print it.
    return 0;            // return all is well.
}
```

This shows how you can use a pointer in a more correct manner.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's because of you. (And that's a golden rule, don't blame the tools.)

The pointer does not point to any memory that you own, so the behaviour on dereferencing it is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

In `int* p;` you define an object `p` that is a pointer to an `int`. This declaration creates the pointer but does not assign any value to it. Defining a pointer does not automatically create a thing that it points to. You have to do that separately.

In `(*p) = 5;`, you say to put `5` in the place that `p` points. However, `p` has not been assigned any value, so it is not a valid pointer. What happens at this point is uncontrolled. Given the message you report, it appears that the uninitialized pointer contain bits that were pointing to an invalid address, so attempting to write `5` to that location resulted in a trap, which the system reported to you by saying that your program is not working.

For example, you could do this:

```
int x = 4;    // Create an int object and put 4 in it.
int *p = &x;  // Create a pointer-to-int and put the address of x in it.
*p = 5;       // Put 5 in the int pointed to by p.
```

Answer (score 0):

By `int* p` you declare a pointer, a variable which is intended to save an address. Since the variable is saved locally and is of automatic storage duration, the variable is not being initialized and therefore holds some undefined value. By dereferencing this pointer you are writing a value to the mentioned undefined address. An important take away for you should be the fact that auto stored local variables are never initialized.

The correct way to do this is to allocate the required memory and assign the starting address of the allocated memory to your pointer.

Comment: Don’t say stack: say automatic storage duration -that’s the term that the language uses.